# override picklist value in visualforce page

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I am using a picklist in visualforce page, through apex:inputField in a form. I am saving that value in custom object. And that value is being saved in object. But when I will open that record in the same form (visualforce page). When the form is being loaded that saved value was there. but when the form has been loaded, the value become null and --None-- was selected.

I tried to use javascript with alert, but it was showing that right value. I couldn't find out the issue.

I have used below code:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="Menopausal_StatusItem">  
                        <apex:outputText value="Menopausal Status:" />
                        <apex:outputPanel >
                            <apex:inputField value="{!msd.AgeVal__c}" id="ageValId" label="" style="display:none;"/>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!msd.Menopausal_Status__c}" id="Menopausal_Status" required="true"/>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <!--<script>
                        alert('{!msd.Menopausal_Status__c}');
                        alert(document.getElementById('pageId:formId:pageBlockId:pageBlockSectionId:Menopausal_StatusItem:Menopausal_Status').value);
                    </script>
                -->
```

This is a dependent picklist (msd.Menopausal_Status_*c) and the controlling pick list is msd.AgeVal*_c.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks a lot like:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957930/lookup-field-in-salesforce-is-null-when-saving

Comment: @Marcel, no. you have problem with saving record. But I have problem with saved record. I couldn't see saved value in my page. But when I queried for that object, the value was there.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with the dependent pick lists. Do you have a value in `AgeVal__c`? If not, `Menopausal_Status__c` might not be correctly rendered when loading it in the Visualforce page.

You could verify this by temporarily making the controlling pick list visibility, to check its content.

Comment: Thanks, this is the problem. I have removed dependency, So now it is working fine. but I have to change value depends on AgeVal__c. Because it is showing all values in Status picklist. What to do? any idea?

Comment: Sorry to only get back this late. In case you still need the answer: do you also save the `AgeVal__c` to the record? If not, when loading it again on the page the depending options will stay empty.